# Can we deploy jbpm project which is currently inside kie-wb to outside kie workbench ? if yes then how?

Tags: jbpm, kie

I have downloaded jBPM 6.5.0.Final-installer-full.zip and installed using `ant install.demo.noeclipse` command.
and started jbpm using `ant start.demo.noeclipse`.
and login into kie, so there are already projects presents.
so for running those project I have to login inside kiewb and deploy it and then run the process.
But can I deploy and run that project outside the kiewb?

My requirements are:

1. To fill form (form1) from customers(which is human user-task) and submit the form
2. and then manager/admin user (which is again human user-task) to receive that data and fill other form(Form2) based on  data and submit it for other task.

So how can I deploy that project outside kie-wb so that I can give customer a url to fill a form?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to accomplish. If you want to deploy and run your project outside of KIE Workbench, you will need to build your own application on top of [jBPM engine](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch05.html) and create your own user interface (render the forms by yourself based on the data retrieved from the task service).

The second option is to deploy your project in KIE Workbench and access it through the [remote APIs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch17.html). You will again need to create your own application with a user interface but you can render forms provided by KIE Workbench using its [JavaScript API](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch13.html#sect-formmodeler-UsingFormsclient).

The third option is to use KIE Server. It is a lightweight application built around jBPM engine which provides similar functionality as KIE Workbench (through remote APIs) except for the user interface. Unfortunately, it is not mentioned in the jBPM documentation at all (only in the [Drools](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/pt06.html) one). But you can find it as [Intelligent Process Server](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html/Development_Guide/intelligent_process_server.html) in the JBoss BPM Suite documentation which is basically just productized version of jBPM and related projects.

Comment: Thanks livthomas Sir, since i am completely new for jbpm so can u share any link or application which i can use as reference.  From where i can get steps to built my own application on top of jBPM engine and create own user interface. Or how can i access kie-wb through remote APIs. Please help Sir.

Comment: You can find a simple application built on top of jBPM engine in [jbpm-6-examples](https://github.com/jsvitak/jbpm-6-examples). It is quite old example based on jBPM 6.2 but it should still work. When it comes to remote APIs, take a look at section [17.2.3. Task calls](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch17.html#remote.rest.task) of jBPM documentation.